# Android - Getting data out of Startapp

Tags: java, android, startapp

I use Startapp as my ad network in my applications and I need to be able to handle when a user clicks on an ad.  I could not find any documentation for this function, and I would rather use onPause() because other things might pause the activity.  Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
YourStartAppAd.showAd(new AdDisplayListener() {
    @Override
    public void adHidden(Ad ad) {
    }
    @Override
    public void adDisplayed(Ad ad) {
    }
    @Override
    public void adClicked(Ad ad) {
    }
});
```

[https://github.com/StartApp-SDK/Documentation/wiki/android-advanced-usage](https://github.com/StartApp-SDK/Documentation/wiki/android-advanced-usage#adding-a-callback-when-an-interstitial-ad-is-shown)

Comment: A good notion but AdDisplayListener() is only for interstitial ads and can't be applied to banners